# The way a 2D list is initialized changes its behavior

Tags: python, list, pass-by-reference

```
square = [[0 for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
square
>> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
square[0][0] = 1
>> [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

This is the expected behavior.

But then:

```
square = [[0] * 3] * 3
square
>> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
square[0][0] = 1
>> [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

It seems like each list within the list is passed by reference to a list stored in memory.

I found this to be weird behaviour since I didn't explicitly create the sublist as an independent variable, and I wondered if anybody had thoughts to share on this...

Comment: *"I didn't explicitly create the sublist as an independent variable"* Exactly. That's why they're all the same list.

Comment: Note that you _can_ safely do `[[0] * 3 for j in range(3)]`.

Comment: Right. But how is `[for in]` different than `[] *` on that level? In neither case I explicitly create a variable.

Comment: Oh great the question was asked before, thanks for finding it.